# The page is not updated after adding an item

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new and just started to learn react. I encountered the problem that when I add an element, I do not overload the entire list. Although the update and deletion work fine, and the changes are immediately overwritten. A new item appears in the list after the page is reloaded.

it turns out, I get a list when I mount the component and I pull it out, and when I add a new element, the state is not aware of its change. Probably you need to immediately transfer to the state what came to me with fetchNotes (). How to create it correctly, please tell me, I have already tried to play with willMount () and do all sorts of manipulations, but either I manage to fill in the state, but then I don’t work this.state.map () or any other nonsense ...
My method for adding item:

```
class Note extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
    updateNoteId: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchNotes();
  };

 resetForm = () => {
   this.setState({text: "", updateNoteId: null});
 };

 selectForEdit = (id) => {
    let note = this.props.notes[id];
    this.setState({text: note.text, updateNoteId: id});
 };

 submitNote = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (this.state.updateNoteId === null) {
     this.props.addNote(this.state.text).then(this.resetForm);
   } else {
     this.props.updateNote(this.state.updateNoteId, 
     this.state.text).then(this.resetForm);
   }
   this.resetForm();
};

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{textAlign: "right"}}>
           {this.props.user.username} (<a onClick={this.props.logout}>logout</a>)
        </div>
      <h3>Add new note</h3>
      <form onSubmit={this.submitNote}>
         <input
           value={this.state.text}
           placeholder="Enter note here..."
           onChange={(e) => this.setState({text: e.target.value})}
           required />
         <input type="submit" value="Save Note" />
      </form>
      <button onClick={this.resetForm}>Reset</button>

      <h3>Notes</h3>
      <table>
      <tbody>
        {this.props.notes.map((note, id) => (
          <tr key={`note_${id}`}>
            <td>{note.text}</td>
            <td><button onClick={() => this.selectForEdit(id)}>edit</button></td>
            <td><button onClick={() => this.props.deleteNote(id)}>delete</button></td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
     )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    notes: state.notes,
    user: state.auth.user,
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
     fetchNotes: () => {
       dispatch(notes.fetchNotes());
     },
     addNote: (text) => {
        return dispatch(notes.addNote(text));
     },
     updateNote: (id, text) => {
       return dispatch(notes.updateNote(id, text));
     },
     deleteNote: (id) => {
       dispatch(notes.deleteNote(id));
     },
     logout: () => dispatch(auth.logout()),
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Note);
```

reducers/

```
const initialState = [];

export default function notes(state=initialState, action) {
  let noteList = state.slice();

  switch (action.type) {

    case 'FETCH_NOTES':
      return [...state, ...action.notes];

    case 'ADD_NOTE':
      return [...state, ...action.note];

    case 'UPDATE_NOTE':
      let noteToUpdate = noteList[action.index];
      noteToUpdate.text = action.note.text;
      noteList.splice(action.index, 1, noteToUpdate);
      return noteList;

    case 'DELETE_NOTE':
      noteList.splice(action.index, 1);
      return noteList;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

action

```
export const fetchNotes = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
    let {token} = getState().auth;

    if (token) {
      headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
    }

    return fetch("/api/notes/", {headers, })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status < 500) {
          return res.json().then(data => {
           return {status: res.status, data};
        })
      } else {
        console.log("Server Error!");
        throw res;
      }
    })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      return dispatch({type: 'FETCH_NOTES', notes: res.data});
    } else if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
      dispatch({type: "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR", data: res.data});
      throw res.data;
    }
  })
 }
};

export const addNote = text => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
    let {token} = getState().auth;

    if (token) {
      headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
    }

    let body = JSON.stringify({text, });
      return fetch("/api/notes/", {headers, method: "POST", body})
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status < 500) {
            return res.json().then(data => {
              return {status: res.status, data};
            })
          } else {
             console.log("Server Error!");
             throw res;
          }
      })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status === 201) {
      return dispatch({type: 'ADD_NOTE', note: res.data});
    } else if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
      dispatch({type: "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR", data: res.data});
      throw res.data;
    }
  })
  }
 };
```

I think that I should somehow call setState in order to explicitly indicate the changes, or maybe I need to re-create the request for the backend as when initializing the component?

I will be glad to any hints and help from your side. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide full code of your component? Including render and connection to the redux store.

Comment: Sorry, added full code of component)

Comment: As you said "A new item appears in the list after the page is reloaded", mean that the request had been sent to API and executed successfully. The problem possibly come from the `reducer`. Hence, please provide your codes where you define the reducer for adding note.

Comment: ok, and action too

Comment: Is `res.data` an array in addNote?

Comment: yes, it is an array

Comment: Please let me know update and delete reflects properly @RomanKovalevsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change reducer ADD case as follow :

```
case 'ADD_NOTE':
  return {
          ...state,
          noteList:[action.note,...state.noteList]
         }
```

Comment: Thanks you, but i got a error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot convert undefined or null to object`
I found this way:
return noteList.push(action.note); in reducer`

I'm not sure that this is the right way to do, and I don’t understand why I returned a mistake, your answer looks right. Nevertheless, he still helped me, at least with the place where I had to fix it.